# selected option from drop down fills another text box/drop down value value

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, arrays

I have been trying to find a solution for this for a couple of days. What I need to happen is when someone selects a "Frequency of Service*" from the form drop down menu, it needs to populate the "Billing Frequency*" automatically. So if the frequency of service selected is "On-Call Service", the "Billing Frequency*" would automatically change to "Per Pickup" and so on. Here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/k4hYE/47/

```
 <label for="00NA00000047Jk8" class="label">Frequency of Service*<select id="00NA00000047Jk8" name="00NA00000047Jk8" title="Frequency of Service" required><option value="">--None--</option>

<option value="On-Call Service">On-Call Service</option>
<option value="Every Six Months (2 Stops Annually)">Every 6 Months (2x Year)     </option>
<option value="Every Three Months (4 Stops Annually)">Every 3 Months (4x Year)</option>
<option value="Every Other Month (6 Stops Annually)">Every Other Month (6x Year)</option>
<option value="Monthly (12-13 Stops Annually)">Monthly (12-13x Year)</option>
```

Every Other Week (26x Year)
     Every Week (52x Year)

```
</label></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the value of another dropdown based on one dropdown selection, you would need to create a key-value array and check the key to dropdown selection.

```
var objArray = {"On-Call Service": "Per Pickup"};
$("#00NA00000047Jk8").change(function()
{
    var ddText = $(this).val();
    $.each(objArray,function(key,value)
    {
        if(ddText == key)
            $("#00NA0000005wIiU").val(value);
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k4hYE/51/

Comment: Thank You, this is Great but wondering how I continue to the next one like "Every Six Months (2 Stops Annually)"

Comment: Ok, so for some reason the first time I carried out the tree it didn't work. It is now but I have a new question concerning this I will ask in another post http://jsfiddle.net/k4hYE/53/

Comment: Fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4hYE/56/ . The issue with your code was that you were overwriting the object array by declaring new set of key value pair. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4hYE/50/

Set a jQuery watcher on the select box, then copy the value to the target id.  Also you may want to use a more identifiable ID for the target, unless you are programmatically generating jquery for each select box.

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    $('#00NA00000047Jk8').change(function(){
       var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "On-Call Service"){
            $('#00NA0000005wIiU').val('Per Pickup');
        }
        else {
            alert('Finish the if/then tree for the rest');   
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Instead of using an exact value match for each option, I would recommend using an array.

Comment: Agreed, an array of source options and destination options would be more optimal than hard coded options.

Comment: Thank You, this is Great but wondering how I continue to the next one like "Every Six Months (2 Stops Annually)"

Comment: In between the `if{}` and `else{}`, you would need to write `else if {}` clauses per value in the select box, and then tell the second select box which value to get just like in the first `if` statement.

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

You could also use `switch` and `case` statements, but if/then is generally easier(?) for beginners?